# xcodebuild: "No applicable devices found." when exporting archive

Tags: xcode, rvm, xcode7, xcodebuild

As of Xcode 7†, the `xcodebuild` export archive step has been giving us errors.

Build command

```
xcodebuild -exportArchive -archivePath "path/to/Thing.xcarchive" \
        -exportPath "path/to/" \
        -exportOptionsPlist path/to/PackageOptions-adhoc.plist
```

yields

```
2015-10-08 16:28:27.409 xcodebuild[62682:464728] [MT] IDEDistribution: Step failed: <IDEDistributionThinningStep: 0x7ff1a42d23f0>: Error Domain=IDEDistributionErrorDomain Code=14 "No applicable devices found." UserInfo=0x7ff1a72ddd80 {NSLocalizedDescription=No applicable devices found.}
error: exportArchive: No applicable devices found.

Error Domain=IDEDistributionErrorDomain Code=14 "No applicable devices found." UserInfo=0x7ff1a72ddd80 {NSLocalizedDescription=No applicable devices found.}

** EXPORT FAILED **
```

What gives? How to fix?

---

† 7.0 & 7.0.1, on Mavericks.

Comment: Try this if above answer can't fix your problem.
http://stackoverflow.com/a/43419887/1982185

Answer (score 25, accepted):

In our case, this was a conflict with our use of a non-system ruby via rvm. To fix, you need to call `xcodebuild` inside the context of `rvm use system`. But doing this is complicated by the fact that using `rvm` in scripts is harder than it should be.

We created a script which fixed this for us:

```
#!/bin/bash --login
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"
rvm use system
xcodebuild "$@"
```

This is a drop-in replacement for xcodebuild, where

```
xcodebuild arg1 ... argn
```

would become

```
path/to/xcbuild-safe.sh arg1 ... argn
```

I've [gisted](https://gist.github.com/claybridges/cea5d4afd24eda268164) a production-ready version. Make sure you `chmod +x` on that file.

Comment: Jeeez, same issue here. Thanks for the fix and Google for indexing it :-)

Comment: This wasn't sufficient for use. We had to unset some more variables after calling rvm use system. I commented the gist.

Comment: @coffeebreaks Thanks, I updated the gist script per your comment. If you get the chance, check the update to see if it looks OK.

Comment: @ClayBridges looks OK. I packaged it for use in fastlane/gym and made it work in non rvm environments. Hopefully it will be merged in a few days. Here's the PR https://github.com/fastlane/gym/pull/176 and the current version: https://github.com/lacostej/gym/blob/features/wrap_xcodebuild/lib/assets/wrap_xcodebuild/xcbuild-safe.sh

Comment: Nice! Thanks for that solution!

Comment: For those building using the XCode GUI instead of from the terminal, I was able to use this solution by closing XCode, running `rvm use system` and then opening XCode up again.  Thanks @ClayBridges

Answer (score 3):

So the underlying issues as as alluded by Clay Bridges answer is that there is an error happening in Ruby. To be specific, this error is being caused by using an out of date version of the CFPropertyList gem.

You can simply update this gem to fix the problem. `xcodebuild` uses the system ruby, so simply do this:

```
/usr/bin/gem install CFPropertyList
```

Answer (score 3):

Make sure xcodebuild using the system ruby.

I fixed it by doing this:

```
rvm use system
```

Comment: EXPORT SUCCEEDED after using this command, but i do not see application running on device, am i doing something wrong? Can you please guide?