# EXPORT FAILED error using xcodebuild command line tool

Tags: ios, xcode, xcodebuild, ipa

I'm trying to export an ipa file through xcodebuild but I always receive this error.

> IDEDistribution: Step failed: : Error Domain=IDEDistributionErrorDomain Code=14 "No
>   applicable devices found." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=No
>   applicable devices found.} error: exportArchive: No applicable devices
>   found.
>
> Error Domain=IDEDistributionErrorDomain Code=14 "No applicable devices
>   found." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=No applicable devices found.}
>
> ** EXPORT FAILED **

Any hint?

This is the shell script I'm using (run in terminal through `sh export_script.sh`)

```
xcodebuild clean -project 'MyProject.xcodeproj' -configuration Debug -scheme MyProject -alltargets
xcodebuild -project 'MyProject.xcodeproj' -scheme MyProject archive -archivePath 'MyProject.xcarchive'
xcodebuild -exportArchive -archivePath 'MyProject.xcarchive' -exportPath 'Export' -exportOptionsPlist 'Options.plist'
```

P.S. Point me out any error in my scripts, if present.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [xcodebuild: "No applicable devices found." when exporting archive](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33041109/xcodebuild-no-applicable-devices-found-when-exporting-archive)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The old way to do it seems to do the job.

```
xcodebuild -exportArchive -archivePath $XCODE_ARCHIVE -exportPath $EXPORT_PATH -exportFormat ipa -exportProvisioningProfile "$PROVISIONING_PROFILE" -configuration $CONFIGURATION
```

where `$PROVISIONING_PROFILE` is for example `iOS Development`. The archive is created correctly. The shell will print out a deprecation log. You can safely ignore it.

The new way, introduced with Xcode does not work (at least for me). See [xcodebuild's new exportOptionsPlist flag](http://www.matrixprojects.net/p/xcodebuild-export-options-plist).

If you have any hint to use the new way, please post it.

**Edit**

There is an open radar for it [Open Radar](https://openradar.appspot.com/radar?id=4952000420642816). In addition, also Fastlane provides a fallback mechanism for this problem (see [Export Failed with Xcode 7 - No applicable devices found](https://github.com/fastlane/gym/issues/104)).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but probably you should specify you need a build for a device.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `-sdk` with proper value (depends on iphoneos with version number)

Answer (score 0):

In my case the issue was related to using RVM. Switching to the system Ruby solved the issue:

```
rvm use system
```

Seams like some parts of `xcodebuild` are relying on the system version of Ruby and don't play nice with RVM.