# Xcode 8.3 xcodebuild exportArchive not working "No applicable devices found" error

Tags: ios, xcode, xcodebuild, fastlane, bitcode

I'm trying to create the ipa file like so:

```
xcodebuild -exportArchive 
-archivePath /tmp/public_1.46.0.2029_production.xcarchive 
    -exportPath /tmp/avner -exportOptionsPlist export.plist
```

The export.plist is minimal (I've also tried stripping it completely and adding/removing various flags)

I'm getting the following output

```
~/Developer/iOS-Scripts/Maxi : xcodebuild -exportArchive -archivePath /tmp/public_1.46.0.2029_production.xcarchive -exportPath /tmp//avner_avner -exportOptionsPlist export.plist 
2017-04-03 15:48:37.428 xcodebuild[5086:564094] [MT] IDEDistribution: -[IDEDistributionLogging _createLoggingBundleAtPath:]: Created bundle at path '/var/folders/rg/8ydk5h297ng50z_3dpkr5jx00000gn/T/InsertViewer_2017-04-03_15-48-37.428.xcdistributionlogs'.
1.2.840.113635.100.1.61
2017-04-03 15:48:46.363 xcodebuild[5086:564094] [MT] IDEDistribution: Step failed: <IDEDistributionThinningStep: 0x7fdc03a02110>: Error Domain=IDEDistributionErrorDomain Code=14 "No applicable devices found." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=No applicable devices found.}
error: exportArchive: No applicable devices found.

Error Domain=IDEDistributionErrorDomain Code=14 "No applicable devices found." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=No applicable devices found.}

** EXPORT FAILED **
```

---

### EDIT

I've tried calling the build using the fastlane script wrapper but still getting the same error:

```
./xcbuild-safe.sh -exportArchive -archivePath /tmp/public_1.46.0.2029_production.xcarchive -exportPath /tmp//avner_avner -exportOptionsPlist export.plist
+ xcodebuild -exportArchive -archivePath /tmp/public_1.46.0.2029_production.xcarchive -exportPath /tmp//avner_avner -exportOptionsPlist export.plist
2017-04-04 10:25:22.726 xcodebuild[16384:848977] [MT] IDEDistribution: -[IDEDistributionLogging _createLoggingBundleAtPath:]: Created bundle at path '/var/folders/rg/8ydk5h297ng50z_3dpkr5jx00000gn/T/InsertViewer_2017-04-04_10-25-22.726.xcdistributionlogs'.
1.2.840.113635.100.1.61
2017-04-04 10:25:32.156 xcodebuild[16384:848977] [MT] IDEDistribution: Step failed: <IDEDistributionThinningStep: 0x7fdde059ff50>: Error Domain=IDEDistributionErrorDomain Code=14 "No applicable devices found." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=No applicable devices found.}
error: exportArchive: No applicable devices found.

Error Domain=IDEDistributionErrorDomain Code=14 "No applicable devices found." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=No applicable devices found.}

** EXPORT FAILED **




~/Developer/iOS-Scripts/Maxi : cat xcbuild-safe.sh 
#!/bin/bash --login
# shellcheck disable=SC2155
# shellcheck disable=SC1090

# Originally from, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33041109
# Modified to work in RVM and non RVM environments
#
# Xcode 7 (incl. 7.0.1) seems to have a dependency on the system ruby.
# xcodebuild has issues by using rvm to map to another non-system
# ruby. This script is a fix that allows you call xcodebuild in a
# "safe" rvm environment, but will not (AFAIK) affect the "external"
# rvm setting.
#
# The script is a drop in replacement for your xcodebuild call.
#
#   xcodebuild arg1 ... argn
#
# would become
#
#   path/to/xcbuild-safe.sh arg1 ... argn
#
# More information available here: https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/issues/6495
# -----

which rvm > /dev/null
# shellcheck disable=SC2181
if [[ $? -eq 0 ]]; then
  echo "RVM detected, forcing to use system ruby"
  # This allows you to use rvm in a script. Otherwise you get a BS
  # error along the lines of "cannot use rvm as function". Jeez.
  [[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"

  # Cause rvm to use system ruby. AFAIK, this is effective only for
  # the scope of this script.
  rvm use system
fi

if which rbenv > /dev/null; then
  echo "rbenv detected, removing env variables"

  # Cause rbenv to use system ruby. Lasts only for the scope of this
  # session which will normally just be this script.
  rbenv shell system
fi

# Since Xcode has a dependency to 2 external gems: sqlite and CFPropertyList
# More information https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/issues/6495
# We have to unset those variables for rbenv, rvm and when the user uses bundler
unset RUBYLIB
unset RUBYOPT
unset BUNDLE_BIN_PATH
unset _ORIGINAL_GEM_PATH
unset BUNDLE_GEMFILE
# Even if we do not use rbenv in some environments such as CircleCI,
# We also need to unset GEM_HOME and GEM_PATH explicitly.
# More information https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/issues/6277
unset GEM_HOME
unset GEM_PATH

set -x          # echoes commands
xcodebuild "$@" # calls xcodebuild with all the arguments passed to this

~/Developer/iOS-Scripts/Maxi :
```

And the plist (in its current incarnation)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>method</key>
    <string>ad-hoc</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: I've seen this sort of thing when the version of Xcode that I used to build the app differs from the version of Xcode that I run tests with. Maybe that is the issue?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following wrapper of [fastlane](https://fastlane.tools/) in order to avoid the Ruby problems on your build

https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/blob/master/gym/lib/assets/wrap_xcodebuild/xcbuild-safe.sh

Replace:

```
xcodebuild -exportArchive -archivePath ${ARCHIVE} -exportPath ${OUTPUT_DIR} -exportOptionsPlist exportOptions.plist
```

By:

```
sh xcbuild-safe.sh -exportArchive -archivePath ${ARCHIVE} -exportPath ${OUTPUT_DIR} -exportOptionsPlist exportOptions.plist
```

It worked for me!

Comment: what do you have in your plist?

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
  <dict>
    <key>teamID</key>
    <string>...</string>
    <key>method</key>
    <string>development</string>
  </dict>
</plist>

Answer (score 0):

I checked IDEDistribution.standard.log and found there suspicious string:

```
Stderr:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/objdump: Mach-O universal file: /var/folders/3p/k32287w14n539kf36w55hldw0000gn/T/IDEDistributionThinningStep.C66/Payload/myApp.app/DeviceStatus for architecture armv7 is not a Mach-O file or an archive file.
```

Sth weird was included in app under Target > Build Phases > Copy Bundle Resources. It could be unnecessary bundles from SDK as well. Deleting reference for this file helped.